# Escaping output by htmlentities() doesn't show the proper content

Tags: php

I applied htmlentities() to escape output from stored XSS attack in my application but it shows the html part not the actual content . I need to escape output in my application for safety . So what should I do ? Please help .

**CODE**

```
   $ml .= '
      <th ' . $listing . ' ' . $listing_class . ' id="' . $x['id'] . '" ' . $listing->listing_width($x['id']). '>
            <div ' . (strlen($x['name']) ? 'title="' . htmlspecialchars($x['name2']) . '"':'' ) . '>' . fields_types::get_option($x['type'],'name',$x['name']) . '</div>
      </th>
  ';

  echo htmlentities($ml);
```

This code **echo htmlentities($ml);** supposed to show a content of a  tag instead it shows the whole html code . What should I do in this matter?? Please Help guys .

Comment: escape `$x`, no need to escape the whole dom or $listing, $listing_class, etc unless its **user supplied**

Comment: I tested my application using some tools to check for stored XSS attacks and they told me to check echo $ml; that's why I applied htmlentities() but now it shows the html part . I have to solve this if I don't then I can't upload my application on production server .

Comment: what part of it is your tool telling you there is a problem? I only see `$x['name']`, `$x['id']` which could be user supplied which you should escape.. as said in previous comment you dont escape the markup just the values which are user supplied.

Comment: If you apply `htmlentities` to HTML markup, it will obviously convert `<` to `&lt;` etc. and what you see is the HTML code in plain sight. You don't need to check `echo $ml`, you need to check what goes into the `$ml` that you echo, ie. potential user input.

Comment: didnt you confuse https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php which doesnt remove html tags from string (but escapes some characters) with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php which removes html tags? Escaping is not removing.